# Analyzer works even without Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll

Tags: .net, roslyn

I have a reference to `xunit.analyzers` in my .NET project. 
This dll depends on `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll 1.2.0.0`, as I have determined using ildasm.

I have no references to `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll` in my project. It is not in my GAC, it is not part of any other NuGet package in this project and it is not in /bin folder.

The above analyzer issues errors normally as I type new code. Additionally, I am using it as part of my build process, in .csproj.

**Questions:**

1. How does this analyzer manage to work without one of its dependencies?
2. How is the dependency satisfied at build time?
3. When running a build in TeamCity I get an error which ceased once I removed xUnit analyzer as an Analyzer Item from .csproj. I do not get this error locally. What is happening here?

   `CSC error CS8032: An instance of analyzer Xunit.Analyzers cannot be created from: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.CodeAnalysis Version=1.2.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to points 1 and 2:**

It appears my local build compiles using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe`, which has in its folder a `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll` of appropriate version, as needed by `xunit.analyzer`.

However, build server uses `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\csc.exe`, which has a version lower than needed and this causes the build to break.

Just for reference and context, `csc.exe` resolves assembly dependencies in order:

1. local folder
2. `csc.exe`'s folder
3. folder mentioned in /lib switch
4. folders under LIB environment variable

**Answer Point 3**

I **suppose** as the analyzer cooperates with Roslyn while I am writing my code locally, it can also satisfy its dependencies from the same Roslyn folder above. This is a moot point on the build server.